# Using 2 buckets inside test container for couchbase in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, couchbase, spring-boot-testcontainers

We are trying to write integration tests for our usecase where we have 2 buckets in couchbase database and I am trying to create test container with those 2 buckets. I have something like

```
new CouchbaseContainer(dockerImage)
                    .withBucket(new BucketDefinition(getBucketName()))
                    .withBucket(new BucketDefinition(getNewBucketName()))
                    .withCredentials("admin", "password123")
                    .withServiceQuota(CouchbaseService.SEARCH, 1024)
                    .withStartupTimeout(Duration.ofMinutes(15));
```

Here I am using .**withBucket()** to create buckets, for single bucket it is working but when I try to create a new bucket it is throwing errors when executing .n1ql files which we are using for creating the base configuration to the first bucket.

It is throwing errors like

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'couchmove' defined in class path resource [DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.github.couchmove.Couchmove]: Factory method 'couchmove' threw exception; nested exception is com.github.couchmove.exception.CouchmoveException: Unable to migrate

Is using .**withBucket()** the right way to create 2nd bucket?

Comment: i think the relevant topic for the problem is here [multiple buckets in Couchbase initialization](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/issues/1022), can you have a look there and retry ?

Comment: Thanks for sharing the relevant topic, I have created the couchbase container similar to what was mentioned in the topic, I have issues with executing the .n1ql files as we use them for creating the different collections we use, issue is with couchmove bean and I am not sure why its having issues there as the 2nd container is getting created properly.

Comment: ok, if you will try to create it without `.n1ql` file, i mean just create the container without anythink.  it is going to work ?

Comment: Yes, it works. I could see 2 buckets getting created in the test container. Just that my issue is related to it running .n1ql files as well with the 2 buckets

Comment: Ok, I am sure if you will have just one bucket all will be executed as expected, just confirm it please with the same ‘.n1ql’ file

Comment: Because i think it is a bug at `Couchmove` if it work for one bucket of course if it is so  you should open a ticket on there GitHub repo.

Comment: Yes, for 1 bucket everything is working as expected, when I tried to add new bucket then I'm getting the errors, there must be a way to do it but I couldn't find it yet. Will try few things today and If I couldn't figure it out then will raise a ticket. Thank you

Comment: You are welcome, i also didn't know  about this case, maybe the guys who work on it can help you, just open a ticket and that is all